# bootstrap-select styling not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-select

I have installed Bootstrap-Select package, version 1.13.1.

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

**PROBLEM**

I want to achieve multiple select functionality in my reactJS + Bootstrap project. However, the styling does not seem to be same as what is shown in the documentation example. Mine still shows 'basic' type of style.

What did I miss?

**WHAT I HAVE DONE**

I have put below piece in my jsx file.

```
class MyTestBox extends React.Component {
//blah blah
render() {
//blah blah
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="selectpicker form-control" multiple>
                <option>Mustard</option>
                <option>Ketchup</option>
                <option>Relish</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}}

var MyTestBox = ReactDOM.render(
    <MyTestBox />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

This is my cshtml file.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Hello World";
}

//blah blah
<div id="content"></div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myTestBundle")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });
</script>
```

As per other posts, seems like I still need to add the URLs somewhere to refer to bootstrap-select libraries. Should I do that as well? If yes, how?

[Bootstrap Select style and search not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721268/bootstrap-select-style-and-search-not-working)

[Bootstrap select picker style not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622549/bootstrap-select-picker-style-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `class` with `className` everywhere because `JSX` does not support `class` `attribute` It replaced by `className` in `JSX`.

```
<div class="row">
```

to

```
<div className="row">
```

You can use `componentDidMount` but I will initialize `selectpicker` code again and again so if your plugin will work fine with this then use

```
class abc extent React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    }
}
```

//second option

use `window.onload`which initialize your code once when your app will fully ready

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
}
</script>
```

Comment: OK i've done it. It seems slightly better now. However, it is now shown as a scrolled selection field, instead of a drop down...

Comment: are you getting any JS issue in `console`?

Comment: Oops..yes, Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function

Comment: I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365047/selectpicker-is-not-a-function). I don't manage the sequence of loading js though...where should I specify the sequence?

Comment: The error was gone, after I added my scripts to bundle (the project is using .Net System.Web.Optimization.BundleCollection). Now the screen is showing previous scroll box (with value list) plus a new dropdown field with no values inside.